# Cannot set side_effect on a mocked method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to write a test for a function that uses a class as a dependency and calls this class method(s).

Let's assume the function is

```
def store_username_and_password(**kwargs) -> Tuple[str, StorageResult]:
    storage = MyDependency(param1, param2)
    try:
        storage.read_data(mountpoint, path)
    except InvalidPathException:
        storage.write_data(data, mountpoint, path)


return (f"Stored successfully {some_params}", StorageResult(some_params))
```

In the test I'm trying to patch `MyDependency` like this:

```
input = {....}
with patch("my.application.namespace.MyDependency") as mock_storage:
    mock_storage.read_data.side_effect = InvalidPathException("the data does not exist yet")
    with raises(InvalidPathException) as e:
        store_username_and_password(**input)
```

However, when I debug it and step inside the function call from the test above and proceed to the `storage.read_data(mountpoint, path)` call, I see in the debugger that there is no `side_effect` set. So it never raises that exception I want on `read_data` call.

See below:

[image]

Comment: you want `mock_storage.return_value.read_data.side_effect`

Comment: Thanks Anthony! Just tried it and still the same: `effect` is None there and it goes further in the flow without raising it.

Comment: actually, there was a typo when I tried your suggestion. Now I checked again and it worked!! Huge thanks Anthony! Could you post this as an answer (possibly with the links where I can read more about side_effect and why it should be set as the return_value of the mock? I'll accept it then. Many thanks again!

Comment: It also helped me to identify another issue I've been having: asserting the number of calls of another function if I check it like `mock_storage.write_data.assert_called_once_with({"some": "json"})` so in this case it was called 0 times, but when I add `return_value.write_data` it all works. Could you send me the doc to better understand why return_data is necessary in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Anthony's comment helped me but I thought I'd add an explanation...

`mock_storage.read_data.side_effect` will work, but only if you call `MyDependency.read_data()`.  What happens is the call to `MyDependency(param1, param2)` creates a ***new*** `MagicMock` that doesn't have the `side_effect` set on it.  The new mock can be accessed with `mock_storage.return_value`.

So, if you have:

```py
storage = MyDependency(param1, param2)
storage.read_data(mountpoint, path)
```

Then to mock that method you need:

```py
with patch("my.application.namespace.MyDependency") as mock_storage:
    mock_storage.return_value.read_data.side_effect = Exception
```

Comment: I have been some minutes trying to spot the difference. The key is the added .return_value. when addind the side effect.